# R - Wald test and Autocorrelation test

Tags: r, testing, economics

Please, how can I do Wald test (heteroskedasticity) and autocorrelation test (from Wooldridge) in R?

I'm using Pooled OLS, Fixed Efects and Random Efects with library(plm) in a unbalanced panel.

Thanks.

Comment: See `lmtest::waldtest` and look at `vignette("plm")` for all the details, especially section 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that provides directions how to perform the heteroskedasticity tests you are looking for using `lme` and `lmtest` packages. There are many comments and recommendations:

http://people.tamu.edu/~b-wood/Maximum%20Likelihood/RLesson%204.htm

As for specifically plm package:
You can find some examples here 
[Waldtest in R to get adjust F statistic with plm and result shown with stargazer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864305/waldtest-in-r-to-get-adjust-f-statistic-with-plm-and-result-shown-with-stargazer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and looking at the documentation of plm package. The `plm` package states: *In
plm we provide a number of joint, marginal and conditional
ml-based tests, plus some semi-parametric alternatives which are robust vs.  heteroskedasticity and free from distributional
assumptions.*

You should also look into lfe package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/lfe.pdf